# ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be longer than the length of string

Tags: c#

When I run the compiler it throws an exception:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be longer than the
>   length of string.

I do not understand why, the string which I write into the compiler consists of 10 numbers, and i want the `substring` to pick the 9th number, but obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Example of string: 9303140456

**Code:**

```
public string kollaKön()
{
    string siffraAsString = form.textBox3.Text.Substring(8, 1);
    int siffraAsNum = int.Parse(siffraAsString);
    int result = (siffraAsNum % 2);

    if (result == 1)
    {
        return form.textBox5.Text = ("Är en Man");
    }
    else
    {
        return form.textBox5.Text = (" Är en Kvinna");
    }
}
```

Complete code, maybe makes my mistake obvious:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public class Person
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        string förnamn;
        string efternamn;
        string personnummer;
        string Kön;

        public Person(string förNamn, string efterNamn, string personNummer)
        {
            string förnamn = förNamn;
            string efternamn = efterNamn;
            string personnummer = personNummer;
        }

        static bool luhn(string personNummer)
        {
            int sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < personNummer.Length; i++)
            {
                int temp = (personNummer[i] - '0') << (1 - (i & 1));
                if (temp > 9) temp -= 9;
                sum += temp;
            }
            return (sum % 10) == 0;
        }

        public string kollaKön()
        { 
            string debuggerIsMyFriend = form.textBox3.Text;
            string siffraAsString = form.textBox3.Text.Substring(8, 1);

            int siffraAsNum = int.Parse(siffraAsString);
            int result = (siffraAsNum % 2);

            if (result == 1)
            {
                return form.textBox5.Text = ("Är en Man");
            }
            else
            {
                return form.textBox5.Text = (" Är en Kvinna");
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string förnamn = textBox1.Text;
            string efternamn = textBox2.Text;
            string personnummer = textBox3.Text;
            string persnr = "";

            if (personnummer.Length != 10)
            {
                persnr = " Personnummer är i fel format. ";
            }
            if (personnummer.Length == 10)
            {
                persnr = " Personnummers är i korrekt format.";
            }

            Person p1 = new Person(förnamn, efternamn, personnummer);
            p1.kollaKön();
            textBox4.Text = förnamn + " " + efternamn + " " + personnummer + " " + " " + persnr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure the string is 10 characters long? Have you debugged?

Comment: If you just need one digit, why not just `char siffraAsString = form.textBox3.Text[8]`?

Comment: can you show an example of what string looks like also set a break poing on the first line and use the debugger to evaluate what `textBox3.Text` looks like also read up on how to access a string based on it's array index position

Comment: `int.Parse` requires a string not a char right?

Comment: @Charleh - `int.Parse` takes a string as it's argument.

Comment: @Charleh That's true, but you don't need to `int.Parse` if you have a single digit (char). A much more efficient simple subtraction will suffice.

Comment: @itsme86 Because that gives you a `char` instead of a `string`

Comment: Exactly, plus `string someString = someOtherString[1]` doesn't compile right?

Comment: the runtime isnt lying to you, that Text field does not contain what you think it contains.

Comment: also make sure the text that you have does not have any spaces.. if so then you want to implement the `Trim()` function as well

Comment: I am curious to know what is that _form_ variable and where do you define and initialize it.

Comment: also read up on the Length function, you probably want to write some code that checks the length prior to just assuming and or using the substring function.. what if the text is `ABC` the substring will always fail.. hence why I am stating to check the text-lenth first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in your Person class

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
```

declares and initialize a new Instance of Form1. This instance is not the one that you have shown on your monitor. When you type your strings you type them on the instance that is shown on monitor not into the textboxes of this hidden instance.

Of course this means that when you write

```
string siffraAsString = form.textBox3.Text.Substring(8, 1);
```

you are taking the text of the hidden textbox that is empty and the following Substring code fails with the Index Out of Range Exception

You need to change you Person class and add properties that receive the content of the textboxes required for your calculations.

For example

```
public class Person
{
    // Sorry but I have no idea of what Siffra means... 
    // change the name as you wish
    public string Siffra {get;set;}
    ...... other properties

    public string kollaKön()
    {
        // A defensive attitude is always a good practice.
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Siffra) ||
           this.Siffra.Length < 10)
           return "Invalid Siffra";

        string siffraAsString = this.Siffra.Substring(8, 1);
        int siffraAsNum = int.Parse(siffraAsString);
        int result = (siffraAsNum % 2);
        return (result == 1 ? "Är en Man" : " Är en Kvinna");
    }
}
```

and in your button click on the form you run

```
.....
Person p1 = new Person(förnamn, efternamn, personnummer);
p1.Siffra = this.textBox3.Text;
string result = p1.kollaKön();
this.textBox5.Text = result;
```

Comment: So I have made the changes you suggested, but my constructor (Person p1) says "förnamn", "efternamn", "personnummer" does not exist within the current context. Any suggestions?

Comment: Forgot to delete a piece of the previous class, it works now. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Before all your code, add this line

```
string debuggerIsMyFriend = form.textBox3.Text;
```

Set a breakpoint on that line, run the code and hover the mouse over the variable to see what it actually contains, I bet it's not the 10 characters string you are expecting

Comment: you mean `add line`not `row`

Comment: it would also be nice if the `OP` would show us an example of the text I am wondering if the textbox has text with a space in the text.. this will cause an issue as well but hard to determine what the heck is going on without seeing the contents of the textbox

Comment: I have added an example of the string now,

Jacopo - if I understood you correctly, it says {Text=""}

Comment: @konto123 That's your problem. You're passing in a start index of 8 on a string of zero character length. Check your length first, see my answer for an example of that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sure that your line `string siffraAsString = form.textBox3.Text.Substring(8, 1);` doesn't have 10 numbers.

Checks the value of `form.textBox3.Text` as say Jacopo.

Comment: What is the point to post an answer identical to another one? Do you think that this is a forum?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please check [answer] for information on how to answer questions effectively on this site.  Check to make sure that if there is already an answer to the question, that yours adds something that the others don't.  Also, try and make your answer clear and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle this more gracefully. This will handle your edge cases properly.

The string you're getting in that TextBox is most certainly not 9 characters long or more, and unless you have 100% certainty that your input is 9 characters, you should handle it gracefully.

Rule of thumb: Don't try to access the index of an array without checking its length first.

<sub>...Second rule of thumb: Also make sure you're accessing the correct UI control if you think something's fishy.</sub>

```
public string kollaKön()
{
    //string siffraAsString = form.textBox3.Text.Substring(8, 1);
    int siffraAsNum = GetNinthNumber(form.textBox3.Text);
    int result = (siffraAsNum % 2);

    if (result == 1)
    {
        return form.textBox5.Text = ("Är en Man");
    }
    else
    {
        return form.textBox5.Text = (" Är en Kvinna");
    }
}

public static int GetNinthNumber(string str)
{
    string numberField = str.Trim();

    if (numberField.Length < 9)
    {
        // Handle less than 9 cases
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int number;
        bool isNumber = Int32.TryParse(str[8].ToString(), out number);

        if (!isNumber)
        {
            throw new Exception("Value is not a number");
        }

        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this does only avoid the exception being thrown. my input must be wrong to the method.